# module-resolver babel doesn't work (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, tsconfig

I configured `babel-plugin-module-resolver` in my **ReactJS** project, i use it coupled to TypeScript.

so, I have my `.babelrc` :

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    ["@babel/preset-env", {"modules": false}],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["./src"],
        "alias": {
          "@modules": "./modules",
          "@screens": "./screens",
          "@components": "./components",
          "@themes": "./themes",
          "@images": "./images"
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
    }
  }
}
```

and then my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "@modules/*": ["src/modules/*"],
      "@screens/*": ["src/screens/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@themes/*": ["src/themes/*"],
      "@images/*": ["src/images"]
    }

  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

For more details of my files architecture, it look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5NsQ.png)

In my file routes.tsx I try to import theme modules

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route as Road, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Route } from '@modules/types/navigations'

import { Main } from '@themes/ui/theme'
```

It return the next error : **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@themes/ui/theme' in project\src**
The import work for `import { Route } from '@modules/types/navigations'` but not for `import { Main } from '@themes/ui/theme'`

The following code of theses files is

```
(theme.ts)
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Main = styled.div`
    background: #000
`

(navigations.ts)
export interface Route {
    path: string,
    exact?: boolean,
    children: JSX.Element
}
```

I tried many path change in .babelrc/tsconfig.json but i dont understand why my modules imports doesn't work apart @modules

Thank you in advance!

Comment: hi, is there any progress with babelrc configuration?